# How to fix numpy array matrix not being read correctly by tensorflow's fit and evaluate function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

So here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from scipy.io import loadmat

# Load the training data en test data
trainingData = loadmat("C:\\Users\\alexb\\vs code python\\train_32x32.mat")
testData = loadmat("C:\\Users\\alexb\\vs code python\\test_32x32.mat")

# Normalize the inputs
trainingData['X'] = trainingData['X'] / 255.0
testData['X'] = testData['X'] / 255.0



# Build the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32)),  # input layer (1)
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),  # hidden layer (2)
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax') # output layer (3)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(trainingData['X'], trainingData['y'], epochs=5)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(testData['X'], testData['y'], verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 32
  y sizes: 73257
```

The problem here is that I use cropped version of the svhn dataset (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/). The problem is that testData['X'] is a 4-dimensional matrix of a collection of 32 by 32 images, for some reason the program read it by entering from the part that has a length of 32 instead of accessing the whole image.

I tries to change the order of the data in the matrix, but this is not a really clean process and it messes things up in other ways.

Comment: What exactly are the shapes of the training data? Their first dimension should be the same, you are incorrect to claim they are not being read correctly.

Comment: The training data is a 4dimensional matrix with a size of 32,32,3,70000ich for the images and 70000ich numbers for the target data. I guess the problem is that my program doesn't read things in the order I want it to and think the thing to read are the 32 colons of pixels instead of taking the entire image.

Comment: The samples dimension is always the first dimension, so your data is not correctly formatter (should be 73257, 32, 32, 3) , also what is 70000ich exactly?

Comment: 70000ich is 73257 and it is the number of images in .mat format that I have in my dataset. Tried to use the transpose funtion from numpy to have 73257, 32, 32, 3 but I couldn't get it to work.